# Не в какую не обновляются данные в таблице MySQL PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Мучаюсь уже блин 2 дня с этой ошибкой. Смотрел в интернете, вроде бы у всех проблемы с синтаксическими ошибками, но у меня весь запрос правильный и без ошибок (да возможно есть), но аналогичный запрос работает, и в отладчике все проверил, все равно возвращает false.

Код запроса:

```
$sth = $this->db->prepare("UPDATE `comments` SET (comm_good, comm_bad, comm, data, comm_state, appraisal) VALUES (:comm_good, :comm_bad, :comm, :data, :comm_state, :appraisal) WHERE `idProduct` = :idProduct AND `com_name` = :com_name");
        $sth->execute($data);
        if($sth->rowCount() > 0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
```

Скрин какие данные принимаются:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И скрин phpMyAdmin с данными которые нужно обновить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**UPD:**
Массив с данными:

```
$data = array(
            ':comm_good' => $good_review,
            ':comm_bad' => $bad_review,
            ':comm' => $comm_review,
            ':idProduct' => $idProduct,
            ':comm_state' => 'Неизвестно',
            ':appraisal' => 'good',
            ':com_name' => $arrP->login,
            ':data' => date("Y-m-d"),
            );
```

Помогите пожалуйста! Ну что у меня не так?

Comment: "и в отладчике все проверил" --- что вы подразумеваете под "отладчиком"?   ........." и без ошибок " --- а сам вывод ошибок в php вы сделали, включили?

Comment: а вот это пробовали: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php  ?

Comment: он и должен возвращать false

Comment: @АлексейШиманский спасибо за быстрый ответ! Как сейчас я понимаю, отладчик позволяет смотреть код по шагом и как раз в моем случаи следит за ошибками, но ошибок я там не заметил. php.net/manual/ru/pdo.errorinfo.php - не знал об этом. Спасибо за подсказку буду проверять

Comment: @АлексейШиманский и что с этим делать? Распечатать и на стенку повесить?

Comment: @Ипатьев можете уточнить почему? Я вот думаю, возможно это из-за неправильного все таки запроса, а именно `(...) VALUES (...)`

Comment: я тоже так думаю

Comment: @Ипатьев Лично вы может распечатать и куда-нибудь себе засунуть

Comment: @АлексейШиманский не нужно обижаться. Ну действительно - что потом с ней делать? Убирать из кода? А потом, когда снова сломается - опять писать? Так и бегать туда-сюда? Есть же нормальные механизмы информирования об ошибках.